# call inject.js method from popup.js chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a chrome extension which modifies page DOM.
I injected `inject.js` and it's working fine.
Manifest:

```
"manifest_version": 2,
"web_accessible_resources": ["js/inject.js"],
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self'  'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",
"background": { "scripts": ["js/background.js"] },
  "content_scripts" :[
    {
      "matches" : [
        "*://*.somesite.com/*"
      ],
      "js" : ["js/page.js"],
      "run_at" : "document_idle"

    }
  ],
"page_action": {
    "default_icon": {                    
      "16": "images/icon16.png",           
      "24": "images/icon24.png",           
      "32": "images/icon32.png"            
    },
    "default_title": "some name",      
    "default_popup": "popup.html"   
  }
```

page.js:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type:'showPageAction'});
var s = document.createElement('script');
// TODO: add "script.js" to web_accessible_resources in manifest.json
s.src = chrome.extension.getURL('js/inject.js');
s.onload = function() {
    this.remove();
};
(document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
```

background.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message,sender,sendResponse){
    if(message.type === 'showPageAction'){
        chrome.pageAction.show(sender.tab.id);
    }
});
```

Now I also have `popup.html`,`popup.js` with one checkbox in popup page. **Clicking on checkbox should call a function in `inject.js`** but I'm not able to achieve that.

I've also tried `location.href="javascript:disableFeature(); void 0";` but chrome refused the inline JS.

Comment: 1) popup.js: chrome.tabs.sendMessage to the content script 2) page.js: in chrome.runtime.onMessage listener send a DOM message via window.dispatchEvent 3) inject.js: add a listener for that DOM message via window.addEventListener (the name should be unique e.g. your extension id)

Comment: @wOxxOm that worked. Thanks. could you add that as an answer

Comment: Actually, I was hoping you'll add an answer with the code, which is why I've only commented.

Comment: np.. will do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to @wOxxOm i'm able to call method in inject.js from popup.js.
Below is the sample code.

popup.js

```
// event is triggered in inject.js whenever below code is run
chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, { method: "enableFeature" }, function (response) {
            });
        });
```

page.js / content.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
        var evt = document.createEvent("CustomEvent");
        evt.initCustomEvent(request.method, true, true);
        document.dispatchEvent(evt);
    });
```

inject.js

```
document.addEventListener('enableFeature', function (e)
{
  // add your code here
});
```

Comment: does this mean I have to own the page I'm visiting?  what exactly is page.js/content.js?